# Why is my showMessageDialog displaying twice?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am working on a simple counter swing app. I'm trying to make it so when you click the check box, it will stay on the top and display a message dialog being "On Top" or "Not On Top".

However, when I click the checkbox after compiling and running, *both* of the messages display, and after clicking OK on both messages, the checkbox isn't even enabled. If I were to remove the showMessageDialog, it would still function properly, but I want to learn how to appropriately implement this.

Thank you in advance. Here is all of the code for the program:

```
public Class Counter {

    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel;
    JButton button, clear;
    JTextField textC;
    JLabel label;
    JCheckBox cbox;

    boolean topC = false;
    int icount = 0;
    String scount;
    String topStatus = "";

    public Counter() {
        gui();
        setActions();
    }

    public void gui() {

        frame = new JFrame("Counter Program");
        panel = new JPanel();
        label = new JLabel("Counter");
        textC = new JTextField();
        textC.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(72,28));
        textC.setEditable(false);

        button = new JButton("Click");
        clear = new JButton("Clear");
        cbox = new JCheckBox("Top");

        frame.setSize(350,80);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.add(panel);

        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(textC);
        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(clear);
        panel.add(cbox);

        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void setActions() {

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                icount++;
                scount = Integer.toString(icount);
                textC.setText(scount);

            }

        }); 

        clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                icount = 0;
                textC.setText("");

            }

        });


        cbox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {

            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

                topC = !topC;
                if (topC) {
                    topStatus = "Top";
                }
                else topStatus = "Not Top";

                frame.setAlwaysOnTop(topC);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, topStatus, "Top Setting", 1);

            }

        });

    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        new Counter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An ItemListener generates two events, one for the selection and one for the unselection (and vice versa). Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write an ItemListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/itemlistener.html) for more information and working exmaples if you really want to use an ItemListener.

Otherwise, use an `ActionListener` instead, it will only generate a single event.